# GreenDao use existing database instead of creating one

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets, greendao

I am using green dao and I came to a point in wich I am supporting multilanguage and I would like to use diffrent databases for each language.

Till now I have been creating my database by using green dao. Now I would like to have multiple databases inside assets and just open the one I need and manipulate it with green dao.

How can I do that?

This is my method for creating the database:

```
public static DaoMaster getDaoMaster(Context context)
{
    if(daoMaster == null)
    {
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(context, "dbSlo", null) {
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }

        };
        //DevOpenHelper helper = new DevOpenHelper(context, "tronpos-db", null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    }

    return daoMaster;
}
```

Now instead of creating one I want to open an existing (dbSlo that I have in assets) and then manipulate with it normaly.

Comment: I have solved this problm by using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13170341/3959584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy before open. Just in the onCreateof your app class call something like the method described in here: [Copy Database from assets folder in unrooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device)

That way you check for preexisting or create the new one by copiying from the assets.